# Can I run my .NET app offilne using the Silverlight UI?

Tags: .net, silverlight, offline

I'm working on an interface for an app that I run locally (this needs to be able to run offline), and I want to use Silverlight's UI.  I use certain references (specifically, Microsoft.Win32) in my .NET app which are not supported by the Silverlight framework, however.  I want to not only use these assemblies, but somehow put a Silverlight-compatable presentation layer on top of it.

It seems like an unreasonable request, but I've been reading recently about Silverlight 4 and access portability and it seems like something like this should be possible.  Am I wrong, here?  If not, how would I go about implementing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with silverlight 4 this is possible and quite straight forward.
See http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures#BlogPost=CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures

an excellent blog. See feature #14, this addresses your question

Comment: Actually, this blog had the answer, but the #3 feature seems to work better for me (just use the shell to invoke my app, and then read the result locally).  Thanks!

Comment: I would, but I don't have enough reps apparently :(  I'm a stack newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you ran your Silverlight 4 application out of browser or installed as full trust application, you still couldn't use classes and assemblies not supported by Silverlight as it's a completely different runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Although technically possible to do your own Silverlight hosting through COM/ActiveX APIs, or hosting a web browser controls, it's pretty involved as you would be recreating a lot of the application framework experience.

You'll find more information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296246(VS.95).aspx

I would recommend *not* attempting this and trying to use WPF instead, since it will be quite similar for presentation and graphics.